# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required

Tags: python, archivo

estoy intentando crear un programa en Python que permita crear un inventario con el tipo de archivo `.txt`, donde pueda crear, consultar y eliminar los productos del inventario, para ver los productos deben de tener su nombre, precio y fecha de caducidad.

El problema aparece cuando intento ejecutarlo me aparece el siguiente error: `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required`, me arroga que el error viene desde una línea en especifico el cual es: `inv = dict([tuple(line.split(",")) for line in inv])` donde `inv` es la lectura de todo el contenido del inventario en una linea.

Este es el codigo completo de la función en donde aparece el error:

```
def consultar(archivo, producto):
    try:
        a = open(archivo, "r")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return ("El archivo " + archivo + " no existe!\n")
    else:
        inv = a.readlines()
        a.close()
        inv = dict([tuple(line.split(",")) for line in inv])
        if producto in inv:
            return inv[producto]
        else:
            return ("El producto " + producto + " no existe.\n")
```

(Ya se que el `dict` solo guarda de 2 valores, en mi caso seria el nombre y precio del producto y saldría sobrando la fecha, entonces necesito que me lea los **tres valores** y principalmente que lo devuelva en un `return` para ver si el producto esta en el inventario o no)

Esto es lo que contiene el archivo `.txt`, en donde el primer parámetro es el nombre del producto el segundo es su precio y el tercero es su fecha de caducidad:

```
Azucar, 15, 31/31/31
Frijoles, 20, 31/31/31
Coca, 40, 31/31/31
Sabrita, 15, 31/31/31
Huevo, 3, 31/31/31
Leche, 50, 31/31/31
```

Comment: ¿Qué esperas obtener en tu diccionario? ¿Cuáles deberían ser las llaves? ¿Cuáles deberían ser los valores?

Comment: Lo que quiero es que el diccionario "clasifique" o separe por coma cada valor (en este caso) para que pueda ver los diferentes campos, el cual necesito que lea los 3 campos (nombre, precio, fecha), de un archivo externo de tipo .txt, y luego por medio del ```if producto in inv:``` checar por el nombre del producto existe en el diccionario, recalco el problema es que el diccionario solo guarda dos datos y pues yo estoy agregando 3

Comment: Una vez que has comprobado que el producto existe en el diccionario haciendo `if producto in inv:`, ¿qué te gustaría que devolviera `inv[producto]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que quieres un diccionario donde las llaves sean el nombre del producto y los valores sean tuplas de dos elementos, donde el primer elemento sea el precio y el segundo, su fecha de caducidad.
Para ello primero convertiremos cada línea a una tupla y después las tuplas a diccionario.
La primera conversión la hacemos como la estabas haciendo tú:

```
product_tuples = (tuple(line.split(",")) for line in inv)
```

Para definir el diccionario tomamos el primer elemento de cada tupla como llave y el resto, como valor.

```
inv = {item[0]: item[1:] for item in product_tuples}
```

Si sólo quieres tener como valor la cantidad de unidades que tienes de cada producto, cambia `item[1:]` por `item[1]`.

Comment: Solo resalto que la conversión a tupla no es necesario, ya que las listas aceptan slicing (como [1:]) y split devuelve una lista.

Answer (score 0):

Esta propuesta es parecida a la @jorge-luis solo que en este caso, algunos valores no contienen espacios en blanco `' '`, también convierto el precio a `float`, considero que un objeto mutable para almacenar los valores es conveniente ya que puedes cambiarlos, como el precio o la fecha.

puedes darle formato a la fecha de vencimiento usando `datetime` de esta forma

```
from datetime import datetime
fecha = datetime(1, 1, 1)
print(fecha.strftime('%a %b %d'))
'Mon Jan 01'
```

para definir el diccionario

`inventario = {i[0]:[float(i[1].strip()), i[2].strip()] for i in [j.split(',') for j in inv]}`

Utilizar valores flotantes para el precio te permitirá operar sobre estos (sumar, restar, etc), en caso de que quieras escribir en algún archivo `.txt` entonces debes de convertir el primer valor usando `str()`

```
# iterar y convetir a string todos los valores con el indice 0
for producto in inventario:
    inventario[producto][0] = str(inventario[producto][0])
```